# How to handle "multiple applicable items in scope" error?

Tags: rust

I'm using the [fltk-rs](https://docs.rs/fltk/0.11.6/fltk/index.html) crate and running into the *"multiple applicable items in scope"* error.

```toml
fltk = "0.10.14"
```

```
use fltk::{table::*};

pub struct AssetViewer {
    pub table: Table, 
}

impl AssetViewer {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32, width: i32, height: i32) -> Self {
        let mut av = AssetViewer {
            table: Table::new(x,y,width-50,height,""),

        };
        av.table.set_rows(5);
        av.table.set_cols(5);
        av
    }
    pub fn load_file_images(&mut self, asset_paths: Vec<String>){
        self.table.clear(); //<- throws multiple applicable items in scope
    }
}
```

Gives error:

```
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
   --> src\main.rs:18:20
    |
18  |         self.table.clear(); //<- throws multiple applicable items in scope
    |                    ^^^^^ multiple `clear` found
    |
    = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait `fltk::TableExt` for the type `fltk::table::Table`
    = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait `fltk::GroupExt` for the type `fltk::table::Table`
```

I would like to specify that I'm referencing the `TableExt` trait, not the `GroupExt` trait. How would I do this?

Comment: I think fully qualified name should work. `fltk::GroupExt::clear(self.table)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: Use fully qualified function name:

```rust
fltk::GroupExt::clear(&mut self.table)
```

Consider this simplified example:

```rust
struct Bar;

trait Foo1 {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}
trait Foo2 {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}
impl Foo1 for Bar {}
impl Foo2 for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let a = Bar;
    a.foo()
}
```

It will fail to compile with the following error message:

```
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
  --> src/main.rs:16:7
   |
16 |     a.foo()
   |       ^^^ multiple `foo` found
   |
```

Compiler will also suggest a solution:

```
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #1
   |
16 |     Foo1::foo(&a)
   |
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler in this instance recommends the correct fix. The error message (as of 1.48.0) contains these help annotations:

```
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #1
    |
18  |         fltk::TableExt::clear(&mut self.table);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #2
    |
18  |         fltk::GroupExt::clear(&mut self.table);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The full error message actually shows 5 candidates and 5 help annotations.

---

As an aside, another syntax for disambiguating methods is:

```
<Table as fltk::TableExt>::clear(&mut self.table);
```

Though its more verbose than the recommended syntax and its only needed in situations where the method doesn't take `self` and therefore can't deduce `Table`.